# Pivot table Mysql

Tags: mysql, join, pivot

I have a table:

| ID | PROJECT_ID | MONTH | MEMBER_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 5 | 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 6 | 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 7 | 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 8 | 2 | 3 | 2 |
| 7 | 2 | 3 | 3 |

I would like to create a table like this:

| PROJECT_ID | TITLE | MONTH_1 | MONTH_2 | MONTH_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | title1 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | title2 | 1 | 1 | 2 |

In each month I have a total number of members. How can I realize it?

Thanks!

Comment: A good place to start would be to swot up on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html or show us what you have tried.

Comment: @bluefeet, That isn't quite the same question though is it? If you took the time to read each question before marking as a duplicate it would help. This one contains an actual SUM, as well as a pivot.

Comment: @Arth I'm pretty sure that the user could get the result using the many examples in that duplicate.  I'm also fully aware of what that duplicate question contained before I marked this as a dup. They would still use either `count` or `sum` as the aggregate function while pivoting. For example [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19009871/426671) answer shows a `sum()`, the difference would be they would pivot the months.

Comment: @bluefeet Yes, they could get most of the way towards their solution but that isn't quite the same. I quote from the dupe box: 'If those answers do not FULLY address your question, please ask a new question.'

Answer (score 2):

Easier answer by @Arth

```
select project_id,
         CONCAT('title', project_id) title,
         SUM(month=1) month_1,
         SUM(month=2) month_2,
         SUM(month=3) month_3
    from table1 test
group by project_id;
```

**[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/947ad/9)**

```
select
    `PROJECT_ID`,Title,
    coalesce(count(`MONTH_1`),0) as `MONTH_1`,
    coalesce(count(`MONTH_2`),0) as `MONTH_2`,
    coalesce(count(`MONTH_3`),0) as `MONTH_3` 
  from
(select
    `PROJECT_ID`, concat('Title', `PROJECT_ID`) as Title,
    case when `MONTH` = 1 then `MEMBER_ID` end as `MONTH_1`,
    case when `MONTH` = 2 then `MEMBER_ID` end as `MONTH_2`,
    case when `MONTH` = 3 then `MEMBER_ID` end as `MONTH_3`
  from Table1) test
  group by PROJECT_ID;
```

**[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/947ad/8)**

Comment: This is hugely overcomplicated: [SEE FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/947ad/9). Feel free to use this as I can't add an answer.